# Pytest parametrized test that uses fixture

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest

I have a test suite with a `pytest.fixture` that depends on other fixtures, like this:

```
@pytest.fixture
def params():
    return {'foo': 'bar', 'baz': 1}

@pytest.fixture
def config():
    return ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']

@pytest.client
def client(params, config):
    return MockClient(params, config)
```

For a normal test, I just pass in `client` and it works fine:

```
def test_foo(client):
    assert client.method_with_args(arg1, arg2)
```

But for a parametrized test, using that fixture is really awkward.  You have to invoke all the fixture methods directly, which defeats the purpose to some extent.  (I should note that the `params` and `config` fixtures are used elsewhere, so I don't want to just collapse them into `client`).

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('thing,expected', [
    (client(params(), config()).method_with_args(arg1, arg2), 100),
    (client(params(), config()).method_with_args(arg2, arg4), 200),
])
def test_parameters(thing, expected):
    assert thing == expected
```

Is there any way to make this cleaner?  I'm not sure this messy code is any better than repeated, similar tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about parametrizing the arguments instead of the result of the method call?

e.g.

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('args,expected', [
    ((arg1, arg2), 100),
    ((arg2, arg4), 200),
])
def test_parameters(client, args, expected):
    assert client.method_with_args(*args) == expected
```